# Connected component doesn't re-render after the redux store is changed.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

My connected component doesn't re-render after the redux store is changed.

The store structure:

```
{
  user: {
    profile:  {
      email: null
    }
  } 
}
```

I am dispatching an UPDATE action creator:

`dispatch(profile.actions.update({email: 'blah@blah.com'}));`

which updates the store state, but *does not re-render* the connected ProfilePage component!

-

/ **ProfilePage.js**  (the connected component)

```
//component omitted 

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { 
    initialFormValues: state.user.profile 
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProfilePage)
```

/ **profileReducer.js**   (where the update action is intercepted)

```
export default function(state = { email: null }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case t.UPDATE:
      return { ...state, ...action.values };  //this is a new object (not mutated)
    default:
      return state;
  };
};
```

/ **userReducer.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import session from './session';
import profile from './profile';

export default combineReducers({
  profile: profile.reducer
});
```

/ **rootReducer.js**

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'; 
import {routerReducer as router} from 'react-router-redux';
import { reducer as form } from 'redux-form';
import user from './modules/user';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({  
  form,
  user: user.reducer, 
   router
})

export default rootReducer;
```

/ **store.js**

```
import reducer from './rootReducer';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import logger from 'redux-logger'

import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { routerMiddleware as router } from 'react-router-redux';

export default function(history) {
  return createStore(
    reducer, 
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(
        router(history),
    thunk,
    logger
      )
    )
  )
}
```

Comment: My guess is that the user object is the same object as it was before

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the user object is the same object as it was before the update - thus redux assumes nothing changed. The profile reducer and using combineReducers in user seems unnesscary and is probably having unintended consequences. You should add a profile field in the user reducer directly and return a new user object. Better yet just put the email field in the user object and ditch profile all together.

Comment: From my understanding, the connect function compares the object/value that you pass in.  So in my case: 

`function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { 
    initialFormValues: state.user.profile 
  }
}`  

would initially have the value of  `{ email: null }`,  and then updated to   `{ email: 'blahblah@blah.com'}`.   

Since this is a different object, the connected component should be re-rendered as it is subscribed to the store.  Or did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have accidentally initialized two separate store instances. The dispatch (called when the App component mounts) was using a different store.  That is why it was not rerendering

```
    class App extends Component {
      componentDidMount(props) {
        const jwt = localStorage.getItem('jwt');
        if(!!jwt) {
**        store(history).dispatch(user.actions.fetchUserData(jwt))    // the offending code
        }
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <Provider store={ store(history) }>    // And here a different store instance 
            <ConnectedRouter history={ history }>
              <AppWrapper>
            <MainNav />
            <Main>
              <Switch>
            <Route path="/login" 
               component={ LoginPage } />
        <Route path="/register" 
               component={ RegisterPage } />
          </Switch>
             </Main>
          </AppWrapper>
        </ConnectedRouter>
          </Provider>
        );
      }
    }
    export default App;
```